# «Настроем» или «настроим»?

Tags: лексика, грамматика, глаголы, существительные

Понял, что существует два типа написания одного и того же слова: *настро**е**м* или *настро**и**м*.
Но, как технарь, не пойму, в чём разница? И почему нельзя одно что-то исключить из языка, дабы оптимизировать его, избежав путаницы?

Answer (score 2):

*Настро**е**м* и *настро**и**м* — это два **разных** слова, исключить какое-либо из языка просто невозможно. Они есть, и употребляются часто.

[**Настро́й**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9) — существительное, мужской род, единственное число. [Значения: [настрой](http://www.endic.ru/ozhegov/Nastroj-17590.html).]
В творительном падеже (**чем?**) — *настро**е**м*.

И даже голоса их, как подкрученные, звучали с одинаковым металлическим **настроем**. [Валентин Распутин. Наташа (1981)]

[**Настро́ить**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — глагол совершенного вида (что сделать?). [Значения: [настроить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).]
Будущее время (мы **что сделаем?**) — *настро**и**м*.

**Настроим** его на рыб, и как только он обнаружит рыбу, даст сигнал. [Кир Булычев. Девочка с Земли (1971)]

― Анисья Тимофеевна, ведь на эти деньги, ― мягко говорит Шулейкин, ― мы заводов **настроим**, больниц… [Булат Окуджава. Новенький как с иголочки (1962)]

**Дополнение**
Вот еще подобные слова (их тоже нельзя оптимизировать):
покоем (покой) — поко́им (поко́ить);
роем (рой) — рои́м (рои́ть);
слоем (слой) — слои́м (слои́ть);
гноем (гной) — гнои́м (гнои́ть);
запоем (запой) — запо́им (запои́ть);
перестоем (перестой) — перестоим (перестоять).

Answer (score 0):

Пришёл к выводу:

1. **"Настроем"** - от слова "строй", "идут строем солдаты", "солдаты идут строем с хорошим настроем".
2. **"Настроим"** - от слова "стройка", "строительство" "строим", "перестроим", "надстроим", "настроим"
   Вроде так.

Comment: Настроем - существительное от слова настрой. "С таким настроем"

Comment: Как по мне, настрой - нет такого слова

Comment: @AndrewCool Такое слово, без сомнения, есть. (http://www.endic.ru/dmytriev/Nastro-1824.html) Я могу полностью раствориться в нежных чувствах к ним ― Черного нет, и некому сбить с меня *сентиментальный **настрой***. [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)] Возможно, спектакль, его истинно *патриотический **настрой***, замечательная музыка Алексея Рыбникова ― все это просто по-человечески понравилось членам строгой комиссии. [М. А. Захаров. Театр без вранья (2007)]